# Is this narration true if so how does it make sense?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

https://shamela.ws/book/9944/19611#p1
The narration says that for a man who has intercourse with a slave woman who was impregnated by another person, the child cannot be taken as his son or his slave. Why is it unlawful for the child to be taken as a slave if it is clear that it is not his son? Furthermore why does it say the child could inherit his sight and hearing when that's not really his child?
also related is the following:
https://sunnah.com/muslim:1441a